# Cannot implicitly convert Ulong to int

Tags: c#

I`m writing a program in c# that tracks CPU usage but i cant get an error solved,

> "Cannot implicitly convert Ulong to int".

Code below:

```
        int i;
        i = 0;
        try
        {
            ManagementClass cpuDataClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor");

            while (true)
            {
                ManagementObjectCollection cpuDataClassCollection = cpuDataClass.GetInstances();
                foreach (ManagementObject obj in cpuDataClassCollection)
                {
                    if (obj["Name"].ToString() == "_Total")
                    {
                        i = Convert.ToUInt64(obj["C1TransitionsPersec"]);
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException tbe)
        {

        }


        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        progressBar1.Minimum = 1;

        progressBar1.Value = i;
        }
```

I`m fairly new to C# so i hope this is an easy fix,Anyone that can help me in this?

Comment: instead of int i; do ulong i;

Comment: That fixes the main error above but now the progressBar1.value has that error

Comment: progressBar1.Value = (int)i; //read more about casting here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Answer (score 2):

ONLY if you are *sure* your `ulong` variable value will practically stay within the range that `int` variable can accommodate, then you can do this:

```
ulong ulongVar = 100;
int intVar = Convert.ToInt32(ulongVar.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Error message is self explanatory..

Your `i` is `int` but `Convert.ToUInt64` returns `ulong` and there is no implicit conversation between from `ulong` to `int` because int type doesn't have enough range to keep a `ulong` value.

As a quick solution, change your data type to `ulong` as;

```
ulong i;
```

but you  still get a problem on

```
progressBar1.Value = i;
```

line since [`Value` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `int` type. And even if you cast it as `(int)i`, you will get different values if your `i` is bigger than `int.MaxValue` or less than `int.MinValue` in `checked` mode.

Answer (score 0):

YTAM`s awnser works:

```
ulong i;
ProgessBar1.value = (int)i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicly you only need convert the property C1TransitionsPersec to a Int32 value.
I searched about the managed class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor that you are using, to view the properties etc, but class I find nearer was [Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor](https://wutils.com/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_perfrawdata_perfos_processor/), AND it was not in Microsoft docs.
The property C1TransitionsPersec is a Int64, so if you do a direct cast, your progress bar goes show a far from real values, I strong recommend you do a proportional convertion, get the max value(or get a value that makes sense) and do the math